# Gettext (PHP) does not work

Tags: php, gettext

I have looked at all the Gettext does not work questions but none solve my problem.
I use the following code to test gettext:

```
putenv("LANG=nl_NL");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "nl_NL");
bindtextdomain("messages", "./lang");
textdomain("messages");
echo _('Aanmelden');
```

I tried echoing the results of all the functions and they return, 1, nl_NL, /opt/lampp/htdocs/SOS/lang, messages.

My directory structure is:

```
/opt/lampp/lang
               /lang
                    /nl_NL
                          /LC_MESSAGES
                                      /messages.po
                                      /messages.mo
```

This is the content of my po file: https://gist.github.com/Merccy/5bd6258e810564e286cd

I also tried to restart my server and I made sure that I have the nl_NL locale but it still doesn't work.

I'm really looking forward to an answer.

Comment: so have you taken a look at the error log? what is your operating system? how have you verified the local?

Comment: also, have you tested with `strace` about which files it is trying to open?

Comment: @eis I checked the locale using locale -a, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, there are no errors in the error log. How do I use strace?